# Load dynamic url in iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, jsonp, bing-api

I have seen something really cool at [Yippy](http://yippy.com/)

They are loading the url in to an iframe for a quick view. I would like to do the same for my website. I'm using the bing API, example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHCT5/16/)

So I appended an iframe and a div to trigger the load event:

```
<div class="blok"></div>
<iframe class="ifram" src="" width="100" height="100"></iframe>
```

And I tried this for the event:

```
$(".block").click(function () { 

$(".ifram").attr("src", (".desc a", this).text() );
});
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's about 6 things wrong:

1. You're using `.click()`, but the results are added dynamically, therefore you need to use a live handler such as `.on()`
2. The element is `.blok` in the html, but you're binding the event to `.block`
3. You're trying to set the src of *every* `.ifram` element
4. You forgot the `$` in front of your selector
5. You're passing your selector a context of the element itself, but the anchor you want to find is inside a sibling
6. You're accessing the text of the anchor, not the href.

The following code should do what you want:

```
$("body").on('click', '.blok', function () {
    $(this).siblings(".ifram").attr("src", $(this).siblings('p.desc').find('a').attr('href') );
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aHCT5/18/

Comment: Incredible. thank you very much:) And thanks for pointing out and explaining in such detail.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a syntax error.

```
$(".block").click(function () { 
  $(".ifram").attr("src", $(".desc a", this).text() );
});
```

you forgot to put "$" before `(".desc a", this).text()`.